# 単独ファイルコンポネント（.vueファイル）にも、vue-class-componentのクラスにもpugプレプロセッサーを利用出来るようなWebpack設定

Tags: vue.js, typescript, webpack, pug

Vue.js [説明書](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#typescript)に依ると、単独ファイルコンポネント(.vueファイル)でpugプレプロセッサーを利用するには[pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader)ではなく、[pug-plain-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-plain-loader)が要ります:

```js
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
}
```

単独ファイルコンポネント(.vueファイル)に加えて、[vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)（[vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)基づき）に確保されているTypeScriptクラスに使いたいなら、どうやってWebpackを設定すれば良いですか?

vue-property-decoratorのクラスにHTML基本テンプレートがインポートされたような [例](https://qiita.com/hako1912/items/8d9968d07748d20825f8#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B)しか見た事がありません:

```js
@Component({
  template: require('./MyComponent.html')
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
    //...
}
```

代わりに、Pugをインポートしたいなら、どうすれば良いですか？

```js
@Component({
  template: require('./RegularButton.pug')
})
export default class RegularButton extends Vue {
    //...
}
```

この場合は、pug-plain-loaderは役に立ちません:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <button @click="onClickEventHandler">{{ lettering }}</button>
 @ ../ReusableComponents/RegularButton/RegularButton.ts 18:18-48
 @ ./SPA_Test.ts
```

pug-loaderを導入しなければいけないという意識はありますが、pug-plain-loaderとコンフリクトが起きないように、どうやって設定すれば宜しいですか?

```
// ...
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.json5$/,
      loader: 'json5-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(yml|yaml)$/,
      use: ['json-loader', 'yaml-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

### 不十分な解決

[pug-plain-loader](https://github.com/yyx990803/pug-plain-loader)の仕様書に依ると、`.vue`ではないファイルに`.pug`をインポートするには、`raw-loader`が要ります：

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        oneOf: [
          // JavaScript(そしてTypeScript)にとって有効
          {
            exclude: /\.vue$/,
            use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-plain-loader']
          },
          // <template lang="pug">にとって有効
          {
            use: ['pug-plain-loader']
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

残念ながら、これだけで足りない様です：

```
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 

  Errors compiling template:

  text "export default "" outside root element will be ignored.

  1  |  export default "<div class=\"container\"><h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1><hr><div><div>V-Model Test：</div><div>{{ vModelTestProperty }}</div><div><input type=\"text\" v-model=\"vModelTestProperty\"></div></div><hr><div><div>{{ defaultTextLabel }}</div><div><RegularButton :lettering=\"&quot;Non default button text&quot;\" :onClickEventHandler=\"executeTest\"></RegularButton></div></div></div>"
     |  

    at Object.emitError (C:\Users\i\Documents\PhpStorm\InHouseDevelopment\mylib\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:165:14)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\i\Documents\PhpStorm\InHouseDevelopment\mylib\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\loaders\templateLoader.js:61:21)
 @ ./SPA_Test.vue?vue&type=template&id=cabf1cca&lang=pug& 1:0-422 1:0-422
 @ ./SPA_Test.vue
 @ ./SPA_Test.ts
```

コンポネント：

```
<template lang="pug">
  .container

    h1 {{ pageTitle }}
    hr

    div
      div V-Model Test：
      div {{ vModelTestProperty }}
      div: input(type='text' v-model='vModelTestProperty')
    hr

    div
      div {{ defaultTextLabel }}
      div: RegularButton(:lettering='"Non default button text"' :onClickEventHandler='executeTest')
</template>


<script lang="ts">

  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

  @Component
  export default class SPA_Test extends Vue {

    private pageTitle: string = 'SPA関連本文';
    private vModelTestProperty: string = '入力された文字はここに表示されます';
    private defaultTextLabel: string = '規定本文';

    public executeTest(): void {
      console.log('試験、正常。');
    }
  }
</script>
```

下記の設定では、全部正常に動いています：

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader'
},
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
}
```

・・・但し、`vue-property-decorator`のクラス以内、`pug`が利用できません：

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  //template: require('./RegularButton.pug') // エラー発生！
  template: '<button @click="onClickEventHandler">{{ lettering }}</button>'
})
export default class RegularButton extends Vue {

  @Prop({default: '規定本文', type: String}) private readonly lettering!: string;
  @Prop({default: (): void => {}, type: Function}) private readonly onClickEventHandler!: () => {};
}
```

使えるようになるには、どうすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私の場合は、これで動いてくれました：

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    oneOf: [{
        resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
        use: ["pug-plain-loader"]
    }, {
        use: [
            "html-loader",
            "pug-html-loader"
        ]
    }]
}
```